# Send off_blockchain transaction using bitcoin address (instant send)

Tags: coinbase-api

When you paste bitcoin address in Coinbase web UI, it recognizes when the recipient has the "instant send" feature turned on and suggests sending the transaction off chain. Is there such a feature in the API?

Right now if you send to an address of Coinbase user with "instant send" feature on, the API always sends it through the blockchain. Coinbase API docs don't have anything like `off_blockchain` param for `send` transactions. Is there a way to do this via API? Or perhaps an endpoint to get a user's email using the BTC address and then sending via that email?

Answer (score 1):

- you have a choice on the "to" parameter on the send transaction in coinbase api

  - if you use a crypto account address, then it goes **on** block chain and incurs fees
  - if you use an email address, it goes **off** block chain and there are no fees

this was only discovered over many hours of trial and error.

we have yet to  test this on the coinbase pro api

Comment: That is true, however when sending via web or mobile app, same is possible with BTC address, not an email. When you paste the address, coinbase recognizes whether the address belongs to a coinbase user and if that's the case and the user has `instant send` option turned on, the transfer to the address goes off the blockchain.